# Removing within the for loop some i that the for loop should go over

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to use an if statement within a for loop iterating over i such that the if statement removes some i that the loop should go over. 
So something that looks like that:

```
iterations <- c(1,2,3,4)
for(i in iterations) { ## i will go from 1 to 4
  if(bla bla bla) {
    d <- bla bla bla ## say, d=4 when i=1
    iterations <- iterations[-d] ## i will now go from 1 to 3
   }
 }
```

I don't think that this code works, though.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could keep a list of numbers to skip, add to it when needed, and then skip over that `i` with `next`:

```
iterations <- c(1,2,3,4)
# Empty list of numbers to skip
skips <- numeric(0)
for(i in iterations) { ## i will go from 1 to 4
    if (i %in% skips) {
        next
    }
    if(i == 1) {
        d <- 4
        skips <- c(skips, d)
    }
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: Nice one, I have written literally the same solution (only difference `vector` instead of `numeric`) but you were faster :)